# can't share project on github because android studio keeps prompting me for my password

Tags: android, git, android-studio, github

## having problem sharing project on git-hub

I'm trying to share my android studio project on git-hub. i do the steps

VCS -> import Into Version Control -> Share Project On GitHub

then i write some description and click share then android studio asks for my password which i type correctly and click login but it keeps prompting me after a second and then again after that. i can't find what is the problem.
i have no problem importing projects from git-hub

i know i'm typing it correctly because if i type the wrong password it will show an error..... Unauthorized - Bad credentials

what is the problem and what should i do?

I'm new to android and and git. please be friendly and helpful to beginners.

Comment: you might need to show your step, so we can correct it..

Comment: If you type in your password, and it keeps prompting you, then you *clearly* have not typed in the correct password. You *are* typing in your github password, right?

Comment: i know i'm typing it correctly because if i type the wrong password it will show an error..... Unauthorized - Bad credentials.

Comment: i'm typing the password i entered in android-studio -> settings -> Version control -> GitHub.it works when i'm importing a project. is there anything i'm missing here?

Comment: In android-studio -> settings -> Version control -> GitHub , click the "Test" button and show "connection successful" ?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you have to verify your github account through your mail. It works like wonders after that.